# Bring viewfrom right to left

Tags: ios

i have this code which shows transition between two view controller but the problem is i want to show the transition from right to left like in a push view controller ....

```
        UIViewController *previousController = [self.childViewControllers   objectAtIndex:[self.childViewControllers count]-2];
    [self transitionFromViewController:previousController toViewController:controller duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent animations:NULL completion:NULL];
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is better approach to what exavtly you want,

```
NSMutableArray *vcs =  [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
               UIViewController *previousController = [self.childViewControllers   objectAtIndex:[self.childViewControllers count]-2];

            [vcs insertObject:previousController atIndex:[vcs count]-1];
            [self.navigationController setViewControllers:vcs animated:NO];
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use something like this...

(Requires < QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h >)

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDuration:0.5];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];

        [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

    [[previousController layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView"];
```